# .checked doesn't change property css state

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

It appears as though my simple checked property toggle doesn't want to work correctly, my function is as follows:

```
$('#enable_payment').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $('.payment-system-form');
            if(form.hasClass('show-fees')){
                swal({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "Transactions made outside........",
                    type: "error",
                    confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
                    showCancelButton: true
                }, function() {
                    //on okay
                    $("input[name='enable_payment']")[0].checked = false;
                    form.removeClass('show-fees');
                }, function() {
                    //on cancel
                });
            } else {
                $("input[name='enable_payment']")[0].checked = true;
                form.addClass('show-fees');
            }
        });
```

Initially on page load, `$("input[name='enable_payment']")[0].checked` is set to `true` like so `<input type='checkbox' name='enable_payment' checked>`

I then wanted to add an alert after it was about to be toggled to disabled, as to which I needed to add the `e.preventDefault()` once I added this I could no longer toggle the the `checked` property?

I've tried doing both

```
$("input[name='enable_payment']").prop('checked', true);
$("input[name='enable_payment']").prop('checked');
```

But, if I run `$("input[name='enable_payment']").prop('checked', true);` within my Google Chrome Developer Tools it works as expected?

So all in all, my problem is that `$("input[name='enable_payment']").checked` always remains **false** & can't be made **true** again once I've clicked the **okay** on my `swal()` function

Here's the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vcz48umx/

Comment: Did you try with change event instead of click ?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif when using change it appears my `e.preventDefault` doesn't take effect, this making my `swal` pointless since it already checks/unchecks immediately

Comment: Can you please provide us with a working snippet

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif added to my post, thanks

Comment: i just tried with the change event and it work as expected https://jsfiddle.net/d8j2caaw/

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif on initial load, click the selector & then click "cancel" it should not set checked to `false` if cancel is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not working because the click event is firing on parent element of input type checkbox which is custom checker so you just need to change click function to its parent

```
//parent() method
$('#enable_payment').parent().click(function (e)
```